# Programming language to use for simple GUI and drawing objects on Linux

Tags: linux, gui, drawing, programming

Me and my team we are working on a team project for university needs.
What we are doing is that we are reading some values from text files and then draw some objects on screen (a big square and a few tiny circles) to make it look like a map. Big square specifies an area (room) and circles the objects (devices) inside or outside the room.
We are also using a simple GUI as a menu with 2-3 buttons and some labels. We have already created the program on C# on Visual Studio.

The problem is that we had to change the operating system from Windows to Linux due to limitations we had (firewall issues) and now we want to create something similar on Linux. We don't care about the programming language we will have to use, we just need something that will allow us to do what we want as easy as possible.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't it just have been easier to solve the firewall issues?

Answer (score 3):

The [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) project should allow you to easily port your C# code to Linux. You can check their [compatibility page](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) to see if the particular components you use are supported.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in another answer because you need to run the same application that was build for windows using visual studio and c#, your first choice should be to try [monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com) which aims at providing familiriaty for visual studio developers in a unix environment.
 In a simple search I found [this handy example](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Building_a_simple_application_using_the_Stetic_GUI_Designer) which creates a graphic application by drag & drop existing gui components.
Another language + IDE you might want to give it a try is Java + [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org) which offers the best GUI support in Java for me(In terms of easiness... it's just drag & drop) and here is a [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html#Exercise_1) I've found.

And a 3rd choice might be Python + [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) but this might be the most complex solution since it will be implemented programmaticaly.

Comment: I tried Monodevelop in the past but was unable to find any help in web in terms of how commands work. Most tutorials for Monodevelop are using different commands and I wasnt able to find how to save and read values in a file. That was my main problem on monodevelop

Answer (score 2):

Nearly two years late, but I would suggest [Lazarus IDE](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/), which is based on Object Pascal. Pascal is not the most popular language around, but with Lazarus it is a very good way to develop cross platform applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with JavaScript, you can try [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) in combination with [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit). The latter enables programming desktop apps using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and NodeJS APIs (for file reading, writing, etc.)

However, if you have lately done a lot C# stuff, I second Michael Kohne's answer to have a look at Mono.